# Poor airfoil choice for wind turbine

Tags: airfoil, turbine

I am getting involved in an outreach project where I can modify a small wind turbine with different wing geometries. Are there examples of standard airfoil designs with particularly **poor** Cl/Cd performance? This way I am hoping to demonstrate the impact of airfoil design (by comparison with better blade profiles).

Edit: Just to be clear, I am looking for something that looks like an airfoil - flat plates and round trailing edges obviously work but "look" wrong, hence the need for a "standard" airfoil design.

Many thanks!

Comment: Which level of fidelity has your model?

Comment: @sophit Thank you for your reply. If by fidelity you mean CFD then DNS :). This project will be experimental - I will be 3-D printing the blades. Fairly low Reynolds number though

Comment: Use a ordinary airfoil but backwards?

Comment: Uh, then you also have to consider stall characteristics, unsteady characteristics and surface finishing (dirt) of the leading edge... I suppose you'd better read some appropriate book like Leishman, which also contain a section about wind turbine aerodynamics

Comment: So basically you are looking for a legitimate airfoil that will be operating in wrong regime (reynolds) when put into a windmill?

Comment: Related: the opposite of https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50689/how-to-pick-a-good-airfoil-based-on-cl-and-cd

Comment: Why not just take all the camber out, or use reverse camber to create negative CL?

Comment: you could increase the part of drag that is not induced by lift, by chosing a thicker version of a standard airfoil

Comment: @TomWaits: I'd suggest to use a standard NACA 0012. It was the first airfoil used on helicopters (and possibly wind turbines) and it has been superseded by more and more efficient airfoils. So you have also a technical and historical background for your choice.

Comment: In current form this is a terrible question without an answer. But interpreting a bit, I think what you really need is just some base level standardized airfoil profile to use for comparing other designs. In which case most people would start with a NACA 4 digit. Then being a turbine the airspeed changes from hub to tip so you must decide if you want twist or taper in the blade, and you could try installing it backwards or at odd angles of attack to see the negative effects of flawed engineering. Thickness matters aerodyn. and structurally, blades bending into the support pole is a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deisigning a wind turbine was actually my senior capstone for aerospace engineering at UMCP (I was on a team that competed in the [USDOE Collegiate Wind Competition](https://www.energy.gov/eere/collegiatewindcompetition/collegiate-wind-competition)).  We used an open source program called [QBlade](https://qblade.org/) to help inform our blade design (I actually took point on this).  What we found was quite interesting.  We tested a couple standard wing airfoils including the [Clark-Y](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=clarkysm-il) and [NACA 0012](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=naca001234-il).  These airfoils produced very poor power curves for a conventional horizontal axis wind turbine (HAWT).

Separately, there are airfoils out there designed specifically for HAWT applications.  NREL has designed the [S807](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=s807-nr), which is reasonable, but for small scale applications actually doesn't work very well.  Then there's the [SG6043](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=sg6043-il), which my team ultimately settled on.  This airfoil is very good in small scale applications.  In our design work, the SG6043 produced a pretty stable power curve across a wide range of TSRs and windspeeds.

Overall, you'll notice that one key difference between the conventional wing airfoils and the wind turbine airfoils is that the L/D curves in the wind turbine foils is more symmetric about alpha == 0.

The 2021 UMCP design report is available [from the USDOE](https://www.energy.gov/sites/default/files/2021-11/umd-designreport-2021.pdf), and goes into more detail about how we came to these conclusions.

Comment: Bravo for a good choice.  By chance, did you get around to trying a jib *sail*?