# Significance of $\frac{C_L^{3/2}}{C_D}$

Tags: aircraft-performance, airspeed

I am aware that this value of lift coeff. over drag coeff. occurs when the zero lift drag is 3X the drag due to lift, and that this will correspond to a specific airspeed. What is the significance of this value/ this airspeed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gliders fly at their [minimum sink speed](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50689/how-to-pick-a-good-airfoil-based-on-cl-and-cd/50709#50709) when $\frac{c_L^{3/2}}{c_D}$ reaches its maximum.

Propeller airplanes fly at their [maximum endurance speed](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50689/how-to-pick-a-good-airfoil-based-on-cl-and-cd/50709#50709) and their [best climb speed](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8365/what-is-the-difference-between-best-rate-of-climb-and-maximum-rate-of-climb/8368#8368) when $\frac{c_L^{3/2}}{c_D}$ reaches its maximum.