# How is the wing area of an airplane determined?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, lift, aspect-ratio

[image: Wing area of various airplanes]

Picture source is from [here](https://aerotoolbox.com/intro-wing-design/).

Here are wing areas of several airplanes. As we can see the **Spitfire**, **B747-400**, and **Mirage 2000**, their wing area are not rectangular. The line drawn from left side to the right side of the fuselage are *not parallel to their fuselage's cross-section*, or they are *not perpendicular to the fuselage*. The connecting line in the drawing of the Spitfire is curving (*bulge*) on the trailing edge side, while the B747-400 and the Mirage 2000 have pointing shape on the leading edge side. As we know that the wing area (hence also affects the aspect ratio) is very critical to an airplane to make it fly as wing area is included in the lift formula, so, what I want to ask here are:

1. Is that depiction correct? If it is correct, then my further question is, why does not all the airplane body (except the horizontal stabilizer) considered as wing area?
2. If it is not true, then how should I determine the wing area?

So far, what I found in many explanations is that the wing is the area from root to the wing tip times two, both sides calculated then times two as there area two wings, left and right. With the information in that link then all calculation will be changed: both wing area and the aspect ratio will be changed, calculation will be affected.

===============

**Edit/Added**:
There is a good article [here](https://leehamnews.com/2015/04/28/fundamentals-of-airliner-performance-part-7-the-wing/) explains about wing area. Based on that article, neither the first nor the second question is true as there is no solid method about how to calculate that wing area. There are three definition about wing area: ***Trapezoidal***, ***Wimpress*** (which is used by Boeing), and ***Airbus***. But what is confirmed from that article is that the fuselage between the wing root in included as wing area regardless of whether it defined according to Trapezoidal, Wimpress, or Airbus' definition.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the reference wing area Sref, span b, and aspect ratio AR are based on somewhat simplified wing forms.  The reference wing extends to the aircraft centerline.

In the case of the aircraft shown, the reference wing probably matches what you've depicted -- with the exception of the 747.  For the 747, the reference wing likely excludes the trailing edge extension and any winglets.

Although these quantities are important for the aerodynamics and performance of the aircraft, they can also be somewhat ignored.

Imagine you have a wing with a very odd shape that is hard to deal with.  You could calculate a simplified reference wing with roughly equivalent Sref, b, AR.  As long as you always calculate the reference quantities the same way for odd shaped wings like this one, you'll be fine.

Comment: What is the definition of, or what do you mean with, Sref? Wing span and Aspect ratio of course no problem.

Comment: Sref is the wing reference area.  I don't really know why we use S for it, but that is convention in aerospace engineering.

Comment: S for surface? .

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I don't think so.  The surface area is a little more than 2x the reference area.  Really it is no more a mystery than why we use b for wingspan.

Comment: @RobMcDonald AFAIK S stands for "(projected) Surface area"

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, S is wing planform of the wing projected from top tangential to the earth. What I am asking here actually what is the meaning of the ref (referential), where it to be referred? Anyway, there is a good article or whatever you call it. https://leehamnews.com/2015/04/28/fundamentals-of-airliner-performance-part-7-the-wing/

Comment: @RobMcDonald, my concern is not about the S notation but about the ref (reference). Where does it to be referred?

Comment: b comes from [Breite (width)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/german-english/breite).

Comment: @AirCraftLover By reference, we mean that it is used in calculations, but it it might not exist on the aircraft at all.  We can use anything we want as Sref. Fundamentally, we use Sref when we turn aerodynamic forces into coefficients $C_L=L/(q\,S_{ref})$. Later, we use Sref when we dimensionalize those coefficients back to forces. As long as we use the same Sref in both directions, we're OK.  When you see coefficient data for an aircraft or model printed, Sref should always be listed. For missiles and rockets, we use the base area of the largest circle of the stackup. It is just a convention.